# Saving file in sd card without extension and access that with extension

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I am downloading a pdf file from server and saving it on sd card without extension (for security purpose so that normal user can't open that file from file manager).For e.g.- I am downloading `abc.pdf` and saving it on sd card with `abc` on below path

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "files");
```

And later I want to view that file by adding extension.
So when I am accessing that file from code by using below code then its gives error file does't exist..

```
String s=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files/" + "abc";
File pdfFile = new File(s+".pdf");
```

So how can I save file in sd card without extension and later open that file with extension.

Comment: You can try to hide the folder or file which is downloaded it's better to do  then rename the file.

Comment: Yes i can hide that folder but in some file manager user can open that hide folder by selecting show hide folder option

Comment: And one more thing if you guys not able to reply then you can not down vote the question

Comment: Are you sure that i vote down your Question ? If you don't have any idea then why yuou try to make an assumption for others

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for your problem is to **rename** your saved pdf file without extension to filename with **.pdf** extension & after completing/accessing view or read operation on your new pdf extension file again you can rename it to file without extension

> Example Usage:

```
String currentFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
            + "files" + File.separator + "abc";
String renamedFilename = currentFileName + ".pdf";

boolean isRenamed = renameFile(currentFileName, renamedFilename);
Log.d("isRenamed: ", "" + isRenamed);

  if(isRenamed {
    //perform your operation
  }
```

Again rename the file if not in use (here exchange renameFile() parameters):

```
boolean renameAfterOperation = renameFile(renamedFilename, currentFileName);
Log.d("renameAfterOperation : ", "" + renameAfterOperation );
```

And here is **renameFile(currentFilePath, renamedFilePath)**:

```
public boolean renameFile(String currentFilePath, String renamedFilePath){
    File currentFile = new File(currentFilePath);
    File newFile = new File(renamedFilePath);
    boolean isrenamed = currentFile.renameTo(newFile);
    return isrenamed;
}
```

In this way whenever you want to perform operation on saved file first rename it to .pdf & whenever it's not in use, again rename it without extension. Let me know if this works for you..